# Push Notifications on Samsung Gear S3 with Tizen 2.3.2.1

Tags: push-notification, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I am working on Push Notifications for Samsung Gear S3 using Tizen Wearable Web Application. My application got Approval from the Tizen team to use the Push Notifications. I followed the guidelines of Push Notifications and integrated the Push Notifications code in my application.

I am able to receive RegId using

```
 tizen.push.registerService(service,registerSuccessCallback,errorCallback);
```

Now when I am connecting to the Push Service using below method,

```
tizen.push.connectService(notificationCallback, errorCallback);
```

I am not receiving any notifications. I tried on both emulator and real device (Samsung Gear S3 Class 2.3.2.1).
When I sent the push notification from the server, I got the success response from the push server

**Request** : 
{
    "regID": "XXXXXXXX",
    "requestID": "273f0307",
    "sender": "Madhu", 
    "message": "badgeOption=INCREASE&badgeNumber=1&action=ALERT&alertMessage=Hi I am a Test Notification"
}

**Response** :
{"results": [{"regID": "XXXXXXXXX","requestID": "273f0307","statusCode": 1000,"statusMsg": "Success"}]
}

Even though I am receiving success response from the Push Server its not delivering the Push Notifications to the device/emulator.
Please provide the solution how can I get the push notifications deliver to my application.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I discovered an error in the logs that indicated that it was looking for the "appData" field. The documentation says that you can include EITHER "appData" or "message", but it appears that you must have BOTH present in 2.3.2. Tizen 3.0 doesn't seem to care.